# docker root crontab job not executing

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, cron, dockerfile

I have an `Ubuntu 14.04` docker image that I want to schedule a python script within to execute every minute. My `DockerFile` contains `CMD ["cron","-f"]` in order to start the cron daemon.  The crontab entry looks like this:

```
0,1 * * * * root python /opt/com.org.project/main.py >> /opt/com.org.project/var/log/cron.log
```

`/opt/com.org.project/main.py` is completely accessible and owned by `root` and has `744` privileges set; so can be executed.

Nothing is showing up in my `/opt/com.org.project/var/log/cron.log` file, nor `/var/log/cron.log`.  Yet `ps aux | grep cron` shows `cron -f` running at `PID 1`.

What am I missing? Why is my cron job not running within the container?

Here are my `DockerFile` contents as requested:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Update the os and install the dependencies needed for the container
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y \
nano \
python \
python-setuptools \
python-dev \
xvfb \
firefox

# Install PIP for python package management
RUN easy_install pip

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

Comment: Where is the crontab entry located? Can you post your Dockerifle?

Comment: @larsks I used `crontab -e` under root user to add the crontab entry.  And please check the OP for the dockerfile excerpt.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: @LearningSlowly no I did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you use `crontab -e`? On the host running docker or in the container itself?

I can't see that you are adding an crontab entry in the dockerfile you provided. I recommend you to add an external crontab file like this:

```
ADD crontabfile /app/crontab
RUN crontab /app/crontab
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

The file `crontabfile` has to be located next to `Dockerfile`.

```
image_folder
|
|- Dockerfile
|- crontabfile
```

Example content of `crontabfile`:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
30  4 * * * /app/myscript.py
```

Answer (score 6):

Why use cron? Just write a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  python /opt/com.org.project/main.py >> /opt/com.org.project/var/log/cron.log
  sleep 60
done
```

Then just set it as entrypoint.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/loop_main.sh" ]
```

Comment: I'll give you some points for a work around solution that would solve my problem, but I'd still like to know why the cron job is not executing...